# NSRunLoop's runMode:beforeDate: - the correct approach for setting the "beforeDate"

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa, concurrency, nsrunloop

I have a doubt regarding the correct usage of NSRunLoop's `runMode:beforeDate` method.

I have a secondary, background thread that processes delegate messages as they are received.

Basically, I have process intensive logic that needs to be executed on a background thread.

So, I have 2 objects, `ObjectA` and `AnotherObjectB`.

`ObjectA` initializes `AnotherObjectB` and tells `AnotherObjectB` to start doing it's thing. `AnotherObjectB` works asynchronously, so `ObjectA` acts as `AnotherObjectB`'s delegate. Now, the code that needs to be executed in the delegate messages, needs to be done on a background thread. So, for `ObjectA`, I created an NSRunLoop, and have done something like this to set the run loop up:

```
do {
 [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
} while (aCondition);
```

Where `aCondition` is set somewhere in the "completion delegate message".

I'm getting all my delegate messages and they are being processed on that background thread.

**My question being: is this the correct approach?**

The reason I ask this is because `[NSDate distantFuture]` is a date spanning a couple of centuries. So basically, the runLoop won't timeout until "distantFuture" - I definitely won't be using my Mac or this version of iOS till then. >_<

However, I don't want the run loop to run that long. I want the run loop to get done as soon as my last delegate message is called, so that it can properly exit.

Also, I know that I can set repeating timers, with shorter intervals, but that is not the most efficient way since it's akin to polling. Instead, I want the thread to work only when the delegate messages arrive, and sleep when there are no messages. So, is the approach I'm taking the correct approach, or is there some other way of doing it. I read the docs and the guide, and I set this up based off what I understood from reading them.

However, when not completely sure, best to ask this awesome community for an opinion and confirmation.

So, thanks in advance for all your help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The code is [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> If you want the run loop to terminate, you shouldn't use this method. Instead, use one of the other run methods and also check other arbitrary conditions of your own, in a loop. A simple example would be:
>
> ```
> BOOL shouldKeepRunning = YES;        // global
> NSRunLoop *theRL = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
> while (shouldKeepRunning && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);
> ```
>
> where `shouldKeepRunning` is set to `NO` somewhere else in the program.

After your last "message", un-set `shouldKeepRunning` (on the same thread as the run loop!) and it should finish. The key idea here is that you need to send the run loop an event so it knows to stop.

(Also note that NSRunLoop is not thread-safe; I think you're supposed to use `-[NSObject performSelector:onThread:...]`.)

Alternatively, if it works for your purposes, use a background a dispatch queue/NOperationQueue (but note that code which does this shouldn't touch the run loop; things like starting a NSURLConnection from a dispatch queue/NSOperationQueue worker thread will likely cause problems).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code I've implemented pretty much does the same thing you've mentioned - the only thing it does not do is check up on the BOOL return value of `runMode:beforeDate:`. Additionally, thanks for the thread-safe head's up. The NSRunLoop instance should only be accessed from the thread that owns it, and not from other threads. For my use-case, using `perfromSelector:onThread:` is not viable, as I'm using a delegate object. From your answer, I think I might have the right implementation. Thanks again. :)

Comment: You need to be a little bit careful: `-runMode:beforeDate:` returns NO *immediately* if there are no run loop sources (`-run` is similar). This is fine if you can guarantee that there's always at least one source (alternatively, removing all sources might be a way to get `-run` to return?)

Comment: Sorry, but the answer is still unclear, and I think also little incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, still unclear. AFAIK un-setting shouldKeepRunning flag is atomic and can be done from any thread. The point is to allow arbitrary user to signal RL owning thread to exit. The runloop needs to process one more "event" to catch the flag-change, but I do NOT understand what kind of "event" will suffice. NSRunLoop docus confuse me. What are those "input sources" which dispatch "events" on the runloop?. Is a normal Obj-C message (i.e. [self performSelector:@selector(dummy) onThread:runloopOwningThread]) considered such "event"?

Comment: Since you need to process an event anyway, you might as well do `[foo performSelector:@selector(setShouldKeepRunningToFalse) onThread:backgroundThread ...]`. In Java you could use a `volatile boolean` to get atomicity and freshness guarantees, but C offers *very* few guarantees when you use threads (and, similarly-but-differently, signal handlers). `NSOperationQueue` will be easier to get right, though.

Answer (score 1):

> The reason I ask this is because [NSDate distantFuture] is a date spanning a couple of centuries.

The method `runMode:beforeDate:` will

- return `NO` immediately if there are no sources scheduled on the `RunLoop`.
- return `YES` whenever an event has been processed.
- return `YES` when the `limitDate` has been reached.

So even if the `limitDate` is very high, it will return after every processed event, it will not keep running until `limitDate` has been hit. It would only wait for that long if no event is ever processed. `limitDate` is thus like a timeout after that the method will give up on waiting for an event to take place. But if you want to have multiple events in a row handled, you must call this method over and over again, hence the loop.

Think of fetching packets with timeout from a network socket. The fetch call returns when a packet arrives or when the timeout has been hit. Yet if you want to process the next packet, you must call the fetch method again.

The following is unfortunately pretty bad code for two reasons:

```
// BAD CODE! DON'T USE!
NSDate * distFuture = NSDate.distantFuture;
NSRunLoop * runLoop = NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop;
while (keepRunning) {
    [runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforDate:distFuture];
}
```

1. If no `RunLoopSource` is yet scheduled on the `RunLoop`, it will waste 100% CPU time, as the method will return at once just to be called again and that as fast as the CPU is able to do so.
2. The `AutoreleasePool` is never renewed. Objects that are autoreleased (and even ARC does that) are added to the current pool but are never released as the pool is never cleared, so memory consumption will raise as long as this loop is running. How much depends on what your `RunLoopSources` are actually doing and how they are doing it.

A better version would be:

```
// USE THIS INSTEAD
NSDate * distFuture = NSDate.distantFuture;
NSRunLoop * runLoop = NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop;
while (keepRunning) @autoreleasepool {
    BOOL didRun = [runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforDate:distFuture];
    if (!didRun) usleep(1000);
}
```

It solves both problems:

- An `AutoreleasePool` is created the first time the loop runs and after every run it is cleared, so memory consumption will not raise over time.
- In case the `RunLoop` didn't really run at all, the current thread sleeps for one millisecond before trying again. This way the CPU load will be pretty low since as  as no `RunLoopSource` is set, this code only runs once every millisecond.

To reliably terminate the loop, you need to do two things:

1. Set `keepRunning` to `NO`. Note that you must declare `keepRunning` as `volatile`! If you don't do that, the compiler may optimize the check away and turn your loop into an endless loop since it sees no code in the current execution context that would ever change the variable and it cannot know that some other code somewhere else (and maybe on another thread) may change it in the background. This is why you usually need a memory barrier for these cases (a lock, a mutex, a semaphore, or an atomic operation), as compilers don't optimize across those barriers. However, in that simple case, using `volatile` is enough, as `BOOL` is always atomic in Obj-C and `volatile` tells the compiler "*Always check thes value of this variable as it may change behind your back without you seeing that change at compile time*".
2. If the variable has been changed from another thread and not from within an event handler, your `RunLoop` thread may be sleeping inside the `runMode:beforeDate:` call, waiting for a `RunLoopSource` event to take place which may take any amount of time or never happen at all anymore. To force this call to return immediately, just schedule an event after changing the variable. This can be done with `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` as shown below. Performing this selector counts as a `RunLoop` event and the method will return after the selector was called, see that the variable has changed and break out of the loop.

```
volatile BOOL keepRunning;

- (void)wakeMeUpBeforeYouGoGo {
    // Jitterbug
}

// ... In a Galaxy Far, Far Away ...
    keepRunning = NO;
    [self performSelector:@selector(wakeMeUpBeforeYouGoGo) 
        onThread:runLoopThread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```